# VS error from std::filesystem::u8path(const char8_t*)

Tags: c++, utf-8, visual-studio-2019, c++20, std-filesystem

In this simple C++20 program

```
#define _SILENCE_CXX20_U8PATH_DEPRECATION_WARNING //suppress VS warning
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    auto p = std::filesystem::u8path(u8"a");
}
```

I get the error from Visual Studio 2019 16.10.0 in `stdcpplatest` mode:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\filesystem(279,13): error C2338: invalid value_type, see N4810 D.17 [depr.fs.path.factory]/1
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\filesystem(346): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::wstring std::filesystem::_Convert_stringoid_to_wide<_Conversion>(const std::basic_string_view<char8_t,std::char_traits<char8_t>>,_Conversion)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Conversion=std::filesystem::_Utf8_conversion
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\filesystem(1442): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::wstring std::filesystem::_Convert_Source_to_wide<char8_t[2],std::filesystem::_Utf8_conversion>(const _Src (&),_Conversion)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Src=char8_t [2],
1>            _Conversion=std::filesystem::_Utf8_conversion
1>        ]
1>test.cpp(298): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::filesystem::path std::filesystem::u8path<char8_t[2],0>(const _Src (&))' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Src=char8_t [2]
1>        ]
```

Except of deprecation of `u8path` function in c++20, I do not see anything wrong here, and the code compiles fine in gcc 11 and clang 12 with the options `-std=c++20 -Wall`, without any warnings. Please help to find what is wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ability for `u8path` to take `char8_t` was a relatively late addition to the C++20 standard. The error in question cites [N4810](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/n4810.pdf), which was a draft that contains `char8_t` (as well as overloads for `filesystem::path` constructors), but the draft was written *before* `u8path` was changed to take `char8_t` strings.

So VS simply has not implemented the [current version of that part of the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/depr.fs.path.factory).

Answer (score 2):

When [P0482 (char8_t: A type for UTF-8 characters and strings)](https://wg21.link/p0482) was adopted for C++20, it unintentionally resulted in `std::filesystem::u8path()` no longer accepting `u8` prefixed string literals (or `char8_t`-based strings in general).  This was an oversight by the author (me) that was corrected (for C++20) via [P1423 (char8_t backward compatibility remediation)](https://wg21.link/p1423).  Microsoft [claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-160) to have implemented [P1423](https://wg21.link/p1423) in VS 2019 16.6 (19.26), but it seems not so for at least this part of that proposal.  [Testing on godbolt.org](https://www.godbolt.org/z/5Yh86xxdn) demonstrates that VS 2019 16.2 (19.22) through VS 2019 16.8 (19.28) and the latest preview release all reject calls to `std::filesystem::u8path()` with a `u8` prefixed string literal when compiled with `/std:c++latest` (gcc, clang, and icc all accept the test in their C++20 conformance modes).

Github user fsb4000 has [already reported this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1941) to the Microsoft STL maintainers (apparently in response to this stackoverflow post).